# Cannot reset the BIOS Password ACER ES1

Tags: motherboard, bios, passwords

Hopefully you all can assist me with this issue, I was trying to dual boot an OS but when I did this I noticed dual boot was blocked by the BIOS.

After entering the BIOS it ask me for a password which I don't have because I just bought this second-hand.

- Tried CMOSPWD but did not seem to work since my PC is 64-Bit
- Removed CMOS Battery from motherboard for over 24 hours.
- No jumper to clear CMOS was found in the motherboard.

I know I could maybe contact manufacturer but since I am no the original owner the help would be less to none.

The computer is an ACER ES1.

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/110108/How+can+I+reset+bios+password#answer113393)? Other than that it appears you need to send it off to an Acer approved repair shop, which as you rightly pointed out will be extremely expensive.

Comment: Another thought just occured to me, could you try flashing the BIOS from Windows? This might wipe out the password.

Comment: How can I flash the BIOS from Windows?

Comment: Most manufacturers have an application you can launch from Windows which will do it for you. Without the exact model of laptop I can't verify that this exists in your case.

Comment: Burgi I have not yet tried that, I sure will and will let you know.

Comment: Ask the seller you purchased it from to give you the password, if possible.

Comment: Solution was the first one Burgi suggested, I basically did this:

GOT IT !!

Turns out there is a page which has the generic BIOS unlock codes.

1° Enter BIOS and put any password 3 times, BIOS will lock 
2° Select option to put password and below you will find a number
3° Enter the number in this website https://bios-pw.org/
4° You will be prompted the number for your device, enter into the BIOS
5° Congratulations !! You may now move the settings in the BIOS (So I can finally install Ubuntu)

Thank you everyone

Comment: Remember to add that as an answer!

Comment: Sorry, first time using the site. Don't see how to mark it as an answer. Mind assisting me?